# AJAX catch returned data if statement

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been pulling my hair out to get this to work but no luck.

I have the below AJAX call;

```
$("#orderverify-form").submit(function(e) {
    $('#loader').show();
    e.preventDefault();
    initiateCall();
});
function initiateCall() {
    // Client side validation
    if ($("#phone_number").val() == "") {
        $('#loader').hide();
        detError();
    } else {
        $.post("php/corder-verify.php", {
            phone_number : $("#phone_number").val()
        }, function(data) {
            if (data.verification_code == 0) {
                console.log(data.verification_code);
                numberError();
            } else {
                console.log(data.verification_code);
                showCodeForm(data.verification_code);
                checkStatus();
            }
        }, "json");
    }
}
```

My responses received from PHP are below;

**Query successfull**

```
// return verification code as JSON
$json = array();
$json["verification_code"] = $code;
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo(json_encode($json));
exit;
```

**Query not successful**

```
else {
    // return verification code as JSON
    $json = array();
    $json["verification_code"] = 0;
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo(json_encode($json));
    exit;
}
```

Code is just a rand number I'm generating. For failure I just set it to 0.
I never seem to be able to catch the error.
Only the `else` part of my AJAX `if..else` statement work :(

Help please.

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a query error? Maybe the problem is in the PHP code that checks for errors.

Comment: var_dump the $_REQUEST object. Start debugging from there.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar.. My AJAX code was correct. My PHP/MySQL were guilty. All sorted now. Cheers!